# Postgresql - work_mem not working?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

my query plan is:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
GroupAggregate  (cost=651964.21..797244.64 rows=4470167 width=60) (actual time=9039.059..10641.090 rows=98433 loops=1)                                |
  Group Key: a.company_id, b.pack_date, c.asal_id, c.tujuan_id, c.barang_id, c.owner_id                                                               |
  Buffers: shared hit=3247 read=82741, temp read=36133 written=36134                                                                                  |
  ->  Sort  (cost=651964.21..663139.63 rows=4470167 width=52) (actual time=9039.027..9820.637 rows=4476009 loops=1)                                   |
        Sort Key: a.company_id, b.pack_date, c.asal_id, c.tujuan_id, c.barang_id, c.owner_id                                                          |
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 289064kB                                                                                                   |
        Buffers: shared hit=3247 read=82741, temp read=36133 written=36134                                                                            |
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=7022.07..158191.86 rows=4470167 width=52) (actual time=533.304..4022.672 rows=4476009 loops=1)                     |
              Hash Cond: (b.scann_id = a.id)                                                                                                          |
              Buffers: shared hit=3247 read=82741                                                                                                     |
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=5599.24..145033.45 rows=4470167 width=52) (actual time=70.472..2360.889 rows=4476011 loops=1)                |
                    Hash Cond: (c.transaction_id = b.id)                                                                                              |
                    Buffers: shared hit=2620 read=82741                                                                                               |
                    ->  Seq Scan on tbl_stock c  (cost=0.00..127699.67 rows=4470167 width=48) (actual time=0.185..837.008 rows=4475997 loops=1)       |
                          Buffers: shared hit=257 read=82741                                                                                          |
                    ->  Hash  (cost=3801.33..3801.33 rows=143833 width=20) (actual time=69.934..69.935 rows=143833 loops=1)                           |
                          Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9914kB                                                                           |
                          Buffers: shared hit=2363                                                                                                    |
                          ->  Seq Scan on tbl_transaction b  (cost=0.00..3801.33 rows=143833 width=20) (actual time=0.036..25.658 rows=143833 loops=1)|
                                Buffers: shared hit=2363                                                                                              |
              ->  Hash  (cost=980.70..980.70 rows=35370 width=16) (actual time=462.751..462.752 rows=35370 loops=1)                                   |
                    Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2170kB                                                                                  |
                    Buffers: shared hit=627                                                                                                           |
                    ->  Seq Scan on tbl_scanning a  (cost=0.00..980.70 rows=35370 width=16) (actual time=449.063..454.444 rows=35370 loops=1)         |
                          Buffers: shared hit=627                                                                                                     |
Planning Time: 0.615 ms                                                                                                                               |
JIT:                                                                                                                                                  |
  Functions: 24                                                                                                                                       |
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true                                                                         |
  Timing: Generation 3.891 ms, Inlining 16.568 ms, Optimization 263.702 ms, Emission 168.218 ms, Total 452.380 ms                                     |
Execution Time: 10709.351 ms                                                                                                                          |
```

I already set the work_mem to 512MB and still get the same result. I dont want the DB using storage sort. How to make Postgre do not sorting the data using storage? Thanks.

Comment: "I already set the work_mem to 512MB" -- but is all that memory actually available when the query runs?

Comment: Welcome to Database Administrator. What exactly do you consider to be a problem?

Comment: You are supposed to tell *us* the problem, not make us guess.  I suppose you don't like the "external merge'? Tuples are packed denser in temporary disk files than they are in memory.  My starting point is to assume it will take work_mem being 3x the temp disk usage before it can completely sort in RAM.  (And when it does, the performance improvement is usually negligible anyway)

Comment: @mustaccio my total ram 2GB, and 1.5GB is available.

Comment: @jjanes Sorry, I already edit my question. Yes i want my query not using external merge, because it takes the highest cost in my query.

Comment: @jjanes I already set mem_work to 900MB and it not using external merge sort anymore, Thank you for your advice.